# How to exclude classes and packages using EclEmma plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage, jacoco, eclemma

I have four projects for which i want to skip the code coverage of some classes and packages in some projects, i am using EclEmma plugin in eclipse.

I checked in Preferences->Code Coverage , in Excludes section if i give some class files , but still it doesn't get excluded in the code coverage report.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately currently EclEmma does not support exclusions from the report as stated in https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/issues/84 (where by the way you received the same answer).